# Postgresql Sequence Increment Automatically with random value

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.5

We are using postgresql 9.5 (AWS RDS) and have 100 of tables but only 1 table's sequence behaving weirdly, current value of table where seq being used is 670 but nextval('seq1') is 20000 and when I run nextval again it is like 20090 and then 20122 etc.
So there is no fix incrementing value i.e. 1,2 or 100 sequence incrementing automatically. Above is the case when I call nextval but without explicitly called nextval seq values gets updated. I have checked all logs of system and code as well but could not find any issue that without using or running insert of table how seq gets updated this seq not being used in any of the table there is only 1 table with this seq.

```
    Type| Start |Minimum|Maximum | Increment | Cycles? | Cache 
--------+-------+---------+---------------------+-----------+
 bigint |     1 |        1 |     9223372036854775807 |1 | no |     1
```

Comment: Was the sequence created with a `cache`?

Comment: No in seq ddl cache value is 1, 

 Type  | Start | Minimum |       Maximum       | Increment | Cycles? | Cache 
--------+-------+---------+---------------------+-----------+---------+-------
 bigint |     1 |       1 | 9223372036854775807 |         1 | no      |     1

@a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Looks like someone is using the sequence concurrently.

Comment: I have checked all running queries (pg_stat_activity) and could not see any (use this seq/table) @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Start a transaction, drop the sequence and wait. Perhaps you see some transactions hang, waiting for the sequence. You can `ROLLBACK` after gathering evidence.

Comment: pg_stat_activity is a snapshot.  If the transactions are very fast, you might not be able to catch them in pg_stat_activity.

Comment: have checked as suggested by @LaurenzAlbe yes some other transaction incrementing the sequence and that led me to a bug in code have fixed it.

Thanks Guys